# Activity is taking too much time from bottom to top animation

Tags: android, animation

I am working on demo application where I am looking to animate an activity from bottom to top.

MainActivity.java

```
Intent slideactivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(slideactivity);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
```

slide_in_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="100"
    />
```

slide_out_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="-100%p" 
    android:duration="100"/>
```

Here I set only 100 milli seconds for animation but second activity is being started after at least 3-4 seconds.

SecondActivity.java

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Second activity first is created and only then animated, you have delay coz you probably do too much tasks in `onCreate` / `onStart` / `onResume` of second activity. Try to remove all "hard" tasks to `async` tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean build your project?
Also, if you run it on the emulator sometimes it is laggy on animations, try it on a physical device.
Code seems good! You should increase the duration though, 700 would be nice.